# Mostrar eventos con multiples marcadores Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, eventos, onclick

Estoy intentando mostrar información sobre un marcador con la `API` de `Google Maps.

Me funciona el `click event` cuando tengo un marcador, pero cuando añado el segundo, no me permite mostrar el evento, solo con el primer marcador.

Se que esto es cosa del código, pero no consigo entender como hacer para que ambos marcadores, al ser seleccionados ejecuten las funciones (`openChart(),showName()`).

```
     //funcion inicializar Mapa
               ....
               for (var i = 0; i < posicionesSondas.length; i++) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(posicionesSondas[i]['lat'], posicionesSondas[i]['lng']);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: mapa,
                    title: posicionesSondas[i].id
                });

            }
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
            openChart();
            showName(marker.title);
        });    

} // fin inicializar mapa
```

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los problemas son:

- Estas asignando el evento solo al último `marker`, *dado que lo estas haciendo fuera del `for`*
- Haciendo la corrección anterior, el problema será que dentro de la función estas haciendo referencia ala variable `marker`, la cual será igual al último creado.

#### Solución:

- Poner la asignación del evento dentro del `for`
- Usar `let` para definir la varible `marker` dentro del contexto del `for`

Ejemplo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < posicionesSondas.length; i++) {

  let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(posicionesSondas[i]['lat'], posicionesSondas[i]['lng']);
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: mapa,
    title: posicionesSondas[i].id
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    openChart();
    showName(marker.title);
  });

}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

hola solo debes ingresar toda la linea de marker.addistener() dentro del for, si lo colocas fuera solo funcionara con el ultimo al cual realizo el marker. Pilas si te funciona.

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta. el problema con esto es que me sale la informacion de solamente el ultimo en todos los marker en los que clickeo. Es decir, click en marker1 = info marker 2, click en marker 2 = info marker 2

Comment: Como dije trata de ponerlo dentro de for. : )